# Not able to send query parameters Mechanize Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize-ruby

I am trying to send these parameters as string

```
abc = authenticity_token=lXewdcVQRHZb+O9gVZ+E0xG9Mtg2rnTznkEN/wVk2a4=&design[design_code]=xyz&&design[price]=600&design[discount_percent]=10&design[category_ids]=148&design[property_value_ids]=250&design[property_value_ids]=285&design[property_value_ids]=499&design[image_ids]=208133&

post_design_url = 'some url'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; ru-ru) AppleWebKit/533.2+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"

agent.post(post_design_url, abc)
```

When i checking out request at my rails server i am getting

```
Parameters: {}
```

I am trying to send arrays in this post request. category_ids and property_value_ids

Comment: Why are you using dollar sign in variable names?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel i needed global variables in my script. Just ignore them

Answer (score 2):

I don't use `Mechanize`, but I think you should add your parameters like this:

```
agent.post(post_design_url, {
    "authenticity_token" => "lXewdcVQRHZb+O9gVZ+E0xG9Mtg2rnTznkEN/wVk2a4=",
    "design[design_code]" => "xyz",
    "design[price]" => "600"
})
```

Comment: This method doesn't work for me. I need to send to arrays and mechanize currently doesn't support sending arrays via this structure

Comment: In this case please add the important parts of your backend code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to **@Sir l33tname** answer you can use following format

```
agent.post(post_design_url, {
  :param1 => 'one', 
  :nested => {:param2 => 'two'},
})
```

Comment: have you tried it out. how do i use it. Assuming i have an array named category_ids

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is right at the beginning of your query parameters.

I believe you should add quotes around the string, and escape your auth token:

```
require 'cgi'

abc = "authenticity_token=#{CGI::escape('lXewdcVQRHZb+O9gVZ+E0xG9Mtg2rnTznkEN/wVk2a4=')}&design[design_code]=xyz&&design[price]=600&design[discount_percent]=10&design[category_ids]=148&design[property_value_ids]=250&design[property_value_ids]=285&design[property_value_ids]=499&design[image_ids]=208133&"
```

I'm pretty sure before, if the quotes around your full string weren't getting you, the = at the end of your authenticity_token probably was.